# Why does Digest::SHA come up with different hashes than those shown in RFC 4868?

Tags: perl, encryption, hash, digest

I'm trying to write some Perl to inter operate with hash functions in other languages, namely Java at this point.  We have found what is presumably a correct source, [RFC 4868](http://rfc-ref.org/RFC-TEXTS/4868/chapter2.html#sub7sub1) which includes some test keys & strings along with their hashed values.  I'm using the following snippet, and can't get Perl to come up with the same result. I can only assume that I'm using it incorrectly—can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha512_hex);
my $key = '0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b';
my $value = '4869205468657265';
print hmac_sha512_hex($value, $key);
```

The output is '4ef7 ... 5d40', though RFC 4868 (and my compatriot's Java implementation) returns '87aa ... 6854'

Comment: Is your key being interpreted as hex properly?

Comment: Good idea, but still no dice:
perl -e 'use Digest::SHA "hmac_sha512_hex"; print hmac_sha512_hex("4869205468657265", "0x0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b");'
224d86ae23ef390be64726e20590bca701e8c5ab1ae865d9e04b0cbc18fd73fbba1ca10a24e162f6399f07d1a2fa86766993ce84dd7a9a826a06144fb9062be8

Comment: Don't quote your hex string. Try print 0xa and print "0xa".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha512_hex);
my $key = pack('H*','0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b');
my $value = "Hi There";
print hmac_sha512_hex($value, $key);
```

Gives

```
87aa7cdea5ef619d4ff0b4241a1d6cb02379f4e2ce4ec2787ad0b30545e17cdedaa833b7d6b8a702038b274eaea3f4e4be9d914eeb61f1702e696c203a126854
```

Quoting RFC:

```
Key =          0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
               0b0b0b0b                          (20 bytes)

Data =         4869205468657265                  ("Hi There")

PRF-HMAC-SHA-512 = 87aa7cdea5ef619d4ff0b4241a1d6cb0
                   2379f4e2ce4ec2787ad0b30545e17cde
                   daa833b7d6b8a702038b274eaea3f4e4
                   be9d914eeb61f1702e696c203a126854
```

P.S. Adding `'0x'` to the string doesn't make it binary, it makes it start with `'0'` and `'x'` ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't ever used, nor understood, pack() and hex encodings.

Answer (score 12):

The test key needs to be 20 bytes where each byte has the hex value `0x0B`, not a string of 40 characters. The test value is the string `"Hi There"`, not the string `"4869205468657625"`. Try this:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha512_hex);
my $key = "\x0b" x 20;
my $value = 'Hi There';
print hmac_sha512_hex($value, $key) . "\n";
```

Comment: Very nice, but I am too lazy to type out all those `\x0b`s.  I'd do: `my $key = "\x0b" x 20;`